# Find common value from two arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am attempting to write a program which examines values in two arrays of different sizes and adds the common elements into a third array.

I am using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    int A[5], B[8], i, j, s=1;
    int* c;
    c=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {scanf("\t %d", &A[i]);}

    printf("\n");

    for(j=0;j=8;j++) 
    {scanf("\t %d", &B[j]);}

    for(i=0, j=0;i<5,j<8;i++,j++)
    {

        if(A[i]==B[j])
            {
            c[i]=A[i];
            s++;
            printf("\n %d", c[i]);
            c=realloc(c, s*sizeof(int));
            break;
            }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to execute it, it is giving the problem that the time limit has been exceed. What is causing this problem?  For compilation I am using the on-line compiler [ideone](http://ideone.com).

Comment: OT: For whatever kind of (more or less strange) indention scheme you might decide, just be consistent in it's usage. In your code I see three different kinds of indention schemes. This is difficult to read.

Comment: Your condition in for loop `;i<5,j<8;` doesn't do what you are expecting.

Comment: Your algorithm has a build-in "off by one" error. It starts with the array C having `1 ` element. This doesn't allow you to return a result of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that would work.

Except for the mentioned problems in the for loops, assignment to array c was wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int A[5], B[8], i, j, s=1;
    int* c;
    c=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {scanf("\t %d", &A[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {scanf("\t %d", &B[j]);}

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
                if(A[i]==B[j]){
                    c[s-1] = A[i];  // use s-1 as an index
                    printf("\n %d", c[s-1]);
                    s++;
                    c=(int*)realloc(c, s*sizeof(int));
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...where to begin?
Are you only looking for characters that are the same AND in the same position?  It LOOKS as though that is what you are trying to do, but as the array A and B have different dimensions, you are going to get into some trouble.  And are you ONLY looking for the FIRST match? With the "break", you will stop after the first match.
Assuming you are looking for ALL element common to both lists -- in ANY position -- you will want code more like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A[5], B[8], C[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        scanf(" %d ", &A[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        scanf(" %d ", &B[i]);

    int ci = 0;
    for (int ai = 0; ai < 5; ai++)
    {
        for (int bi = 0; bi < 8; bi++)
        {
            if (A[ai] == B[bi])
            {
                C[ci] = A[ai];
                ci++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    C[ci] = 0;
    printf("Common chars: %s\n", C);

    return 0;
}
```

The key to what you want, I think, is the nested for loops, which iterate through EACH of the strings (A and B) separately, while looking for matching characters.